# Manifolds and Varieties

Tags: notation

In my language, spanish, the word for (topological) manifold and (algebraic) variety is the same: "Variedad". This happens also in some other languages, like french (variété) or portuguese (variedade).

Is there a mathematical link between these two concepts that justifies this linguistic fact?

Comment: Sure. The common ground was surfaces in $\mathbb R^3.$ Manifold comes from the German, it is originally an adjective, Riemann's phrase amounts to "many times" or manifold extended aggregates. Compare twofold, threefold.

Comment: Yes. John Nash, better known for Nash equilibrium, once proved that all (real) manifolds are homeomorphic to some algebraic variety. http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1969649?uid=3739920&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21104338172697

Comment: I think the more basic point is that every smooth variety (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) is naturally also a smooth manifold.

Comment: Yes, but Nash's partial converse is more surprising, and has the benefit of making them come on equal footing rather than considering manifold to be the truly "more general" concept.

Comment: The name is the same also in Czech: “varieta”.